# Exponential definition

Tags: exponentiation, real-numbers, cauchy-sequences

I was wandering the following:

> Suppose two $\mathbb Q$-valued Cauchy sequences $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ are equivalent provided $a_n-b_n \to 0$. We may define $\mathbb R$ as the quotient set of the set of all $\mathbb Q$-valued Cauchy sequences with respect to the above equivalence relation.
>
> Then we may easily define the sums, products and hence rational powers of real numbers.
>
> However, does it make sense to **extend** the definition to real powers? Namely, suppose $a, b \in \mathbb R$ with $a >0$ and suppose $ \mathbb Q\ni b_n \to b$. Is the following definition
>
> $$a^b := \lim_{n \to \infty} a^{b_n}$$
>
> consistent (i.e. does the limit exist and is the same for all $\mathbb Q \ni b_n \to b$)?

My reason for asking is that I've always seen $a^b$ formally defined as $\exp(b \log a)$ and I was wandering if such machinery is really needed or we can give a more "elementary" definition of real exponentiation without invoking the knowledge of $\exp$ and $\log$.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Short answer: yes you can do that.

Comment: @EthanBolker do you have any reference I could look into?

Comment: It's an exercise in rudin's principals if mathematical analysis chapter 1.  The idea is to show sup b^q; q < x exists and for x rational sup b^q; q < x is b^x so such a definition is well defined and consistent.  Then you show b^xb^y eb^{x+y} still holds.